# Grouping query result into 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

```
Group | Count 1 | Count 2 | Count 3
-----------------------------------
Grp 1 | (null)  |    54   |  (null)
Grp 1 | (null)  |  (null) |    52
Grp 1 |   55    |  (null) |  (null)
Grp 2 |   62    |  (null) |  (null)
Grp 2 | (null)  |    56   |  (null)
Grp 2 | (null)  |  (null) |    32
```

This is how my query's result currently looks like, How do I group them so that each "Grp" is only 1 row like this.

```
Group | Count 1 | Count 2 | Count 3
-----------------------------------
Grp 1 |   55    |    54   |    52
Grp 2 |   62    |    56   |    32
```

Comment: Use `MAX([Count 1]), MAX([Count 2]), MAX([Count 3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with aggregation function such as `SUM` (or `MAX` as you need):

```
select
    "Group"
    sum(Count_1) count_1,
    sum(Count_2) count_2,
    sum(Count_3) count_3
from your_table
group by "Group";
```

Also, try not to use reserved keywords such as `GROUP` etc as table or column identifiers.

Comment: Thank you, i'll accept the answer later because I can't do it right now.